# Error when building android_core

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20ROS%20Development%20Environment:

When I catkin_make I get the following error msg:

> path-to-android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: path-to-android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

> :android_10:processReleaseResources FAILED

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':android_10:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Per other threads I've attempted rolling back my build tools version to 23.0.3 however 25.0.2 gets re-added and used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265289/error-when-building-android_core/) by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2017-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: The issue was, that for some reason I was using a 32bit version of Ubuntu and Android Studio now only supports 64bit systems. Flashing 64bit Ubuntu solved the issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) with karma: 77 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0